# Closing WebBrowser form opens URL in standard browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

After some actions I use `this.Close();` in C#, which should close form with WebBrowser element. But after closing it my standard installed browser(Chrome) opens with the last URL from WebBrowser element. How can I avoid this?
Code I'm using

```
public Vk_connect()
    {
        string url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=" + appID + "&scope=friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,wall,messages&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=popup&response_type=token";
        this.Text = "Connect to VK";
        InitializeComponent();
        this.vkconnect.Navigate(url);
        vkconnect.Navigated += vkconnect_Navigated;
    }

    void vkconnect_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        token = vkconnect.Url.ToString();
        if (token.Contains("#access_token"))
        {
            token = token.Split('#')[1];
            id = token.Split('=')[3];
            token = token.Split('&')[0];
            token = token.Split('=')[1];
            config.token = token;
            config.userid = id;
            vkconnect.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: depends what your code does..

Comment: Should I post the whole code somewhere?

Comment: @Amator, just post the code here by Editing your question, not adding it in a comment.

Comment: Is it enough(part of code)?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. The only solution I have found is to add a slight delay before closing the form. It's a very dirty solution, but all other events like DocumentCompleted have the exact same issue.

Have you found a valid solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am checking whether browser has finished all redirections by looking at `webBrowser1.StatusText`.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.StatusText.Equals("Done"))
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```